# Better understanding of Distributions functions

Tags: r

When we use a distribution in R the command is always  **d**norm,**p**norm,**q**norm, for example. Is there a way to find the formulas for this distributions?

It would be nice If I could see every distribution in this way:

```
`dgumbel <- function(x,mu,s){ # PDF
exp((mu - x)/s - exp((mu - x)/s))/s
}

 pgumbel <- function(q,mu,s){ # CDF
 exp(-exp(-((q - mu)/s)))
  }

 qgumbel <- function(p, mu, s){ # quantile function
 mu-s*log(-log(p))
 }`
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Study the documentation. However, not every distribution is that simple. E.g., the normal CDF involves an integral. Also, often these R functions use approximations or optimizations for extreme tails and such. Furthermore, most of them are implemented in C code.

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function

Comment: One of my favorite references is "Statistical Distributions" by Forbes, Evans, et. al.  It has a couple of brief chapters reviewing the overall theory and then a series of a few dozen brief chapters, each discussing a standard distribution, with information about formulas,parameters, moment generating functions, etc. The current (4th) edition seems a bit pricey on Amazon, though you could doubtless pick up a used earlier edition for less (I use the second edition).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advices!